# Why won't my netherportal light/work?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

First, I built a Nether Core Reactor (using the core, gold blocks, and cobblestone) and that worked. Instantly, it turned into obsidian. It used to occasionally light up and it would shoot out items. I dug up the obsidian with a diamond pic axe (all of it). I then went into a grassland and created the 4x5 nether portal using the obsidian, but whenever I went to light the inner on fire using flint and steel it light the obsidian on actual fire instead of making the portal. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: A screenshot of exactly what you have built would help immensely.

Comment: Did the nether fortress and zombie pigmen appear?

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, you can't go to the Nether in Minecraft PE. Nether portals made from obsidian will not activate. However, development is still going on. They might be added later.

I'm not sure why your Nether *Reactor* wasn't working.